# how do I convert a non gui user into a gui user

Tags: permissions, gui

I need to log into the ubuntu desktop as 'jenkins', but I guess the applies to converting any non gui user to a gui user.

I think I did this before by creating the jenkins user in the control panel before installing jenkins.  However, this time I already have jenkins installed, and already have the jenkins user created.

So I guess there must be a group or something that I have to add jenkins to so that it appears in the login menu?

---

or put another way, how do I get one of the users from /etc/passwd on to this list:

[image]

Comment: I don't think there are GUI and nonGUI users. Try to login as other user where you can type in a username too.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no distinction between GUI users and non-GUI users: instead, there's conventionally a distinction between *system users* and *non-system users*.

System users have low numeric UID: specifically, the `/etc/login.defs` file defines

```
#
# Min/max values for automatic uid selection in useradd
#
UID_MIN                  1000
UID_MAX                 60000
# System accounts
#SYS_UID_MIN              100
#SYS_UID_MAX              999
```

GUI display managers like `lightdm` are typically configured to ignore system accounts: in `lightdm`, that's done using a configuration option `minimum-uid`:

```
[UserList]
minimum-uid=500
hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess
hidden-shells=/bin/false /usr/sbin/nologin
```

Why is `minimum-uid` 500 not 1000? AFAIK that's for compatibility with other systems, in particular OSX which uses a `UID_MIN` of 500

To actually log in, the user will also need a valid login shell (as specified in the `/etc/shells` file) and to log in with a GUI session, they also need a writeable home directory.